# UWP Begin Storyboard on an object created from a GridView.ItemTemplate DataTemplate using an Image Tapped Event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, storyboard

I have used the Microsoft docs and sites such as this and have had some success but I cannot achieve my goal.

I would like an image tap to start a storyboard, the image tap comes from an instance of an object that is within a gridview.

```
<GridView ItemSource="{Binding"}>
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTempate>
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
<Storyboard>
<!-- storyboard code here no worries it works outside the data template-->
</Storyboard>
<Image Tapped="Image_Tapped" Source="assets/stuff/stuff.png">
</Image>
```

Within the DataTemplate there is an image and I would like the tapped event of that image to start the storyboard relating to that instance. The Gridview.DataContext comes from an ObservableCollection`<Player>`. Player is a class I have written which contains some string and int properties and uses INotifyPropertyChanged

I've tried

```
<Image>
<Image.Triggers>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="">
<!--this only works when the UIElement is loaded-->
```

I thought I was getting somewhere using the EventTrigger but I need the storyboard to begin on an image tap or button click or some form of user input like that.

I have also tried moving the storyboard into various xaml locations and using

```
this.Resources["MyStoryboard"]as Storyboard).Begin();
```

Any help ideas would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Success! I knew there would be a simple way to do this.

Okay to re cap

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!--stuff like columns and rows etc etc-->
                <Image x:Name="MyImageToAnimate" source="assets/stuff/stuff.png"/>
                <!--other bits etc-->
                <Image x:Name="ImageThatUserTaps" source="assets/stuff/other_stuff.png">
                    <Image.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard">
                            <!--write your storyboard here-->
                                <!--my storyboard targets the opacity of "MyImageToAnimate"-->
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Image.Resources>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

So the above code is my xaml and I have put the storyboard inside the image resources. Then in code behind...

```
private void ImageThatUserTaps_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = (sender as Image).Resources["MyStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
    sb.Begin();
}
```

That has been causing me upset for far too long and as usual there was a nice simple solution just a smidge out of view.

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't be `Tapped=__` it should be the event handler for button click. Use a button and surround the image with it.

```
<Button onClick="buttonClicked">
<Image/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. Ive tried something similar to your suggestion and it fails because UWP is limited and the EventTrigger happens when the UIElement is loaded and I need it on a click or tap event. Other code is fired when I tap the image its just the storyboard issue.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know if an image can be made clickable in a simple way. I thing it takes a lot more. However your can surround the image instead of a button, with an AppBarButton and delete the image. Instead, make the icon of the ABB your image using an external resource icon.

Comment: Hmm I feel you are missing the point of the question. I have code that gets called from the Image Tapped event. It is possible in UWP xaml to have this tapped event. My question is making a storyboard start when the image is tapped. At the moment the image tapped event causes a player to lose life and I can see this happens by looking at that instance of a player class objects. What I need is to access or call the storyboard that is defined in the data template that represents the player class object in xaml

Comment: Ok, then don't use the event trigger. Instead, use the code behind (c#, Visual Basic, what have you) and route the image tapped event handler to there.

Comment: But how do I start the storyboard? FYI Storyboard.Begin(); wont work as its within a data template.

Comment: Try naming the storyboard

Comment: Just read your comment, yes providing a string of the storyboard name is useful now I can see how to access it.
However,
My question wouldn't be answered by wrapping the image inside a button.
Thank you for trying to help though, it was bugging me for a good week. :)

Comment: No problem. It's always good to name your elements, even if you don't need to. It works better to use the name, and something it's the only thing the program recognizes.

Comment: I gave a poor code example in my question which I think gave you this no name idea. I do actually name nearly all my xaml elements.